# Error puting jenkins stage inside a function definition

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using scripted pipeline and trying to put my stage inside a function as below.

```
   node{
          if(value=="true")
             {
              def func(){
                       stage ('first stage')
               }
              }      
              fun() #calling it here. 

}
```

its not working. it says method definition not expected here

> Method definition not expected here. Please define the method at an
> appropriate place or perhaps try using a block/Closure instead.

. How to do this? its not possible to define outside node block as the pipeline is running on a particular node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without executing the stage, you can return the stage configurations from a function. Please refer to the following.

```
node {
    stage('Stage 1') {
       echo "This stage executed always"
    }
    def value = true
    // Lets execute stage 2
    if(value == true) {
        generateStage("Stage 2").call()
    }
    
    stage('Stage3') {
        echo "Stage 3"
    }
}

def generateStage(name) {
    return {
        stage("Stage ${name}") {
            echo "Stage ${name}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you defined the function outside nodeblock which works. In my case I have to put stage inside the function definition. It does not work.

Comment: Yes, but what's the difference?

Comment: If I put the function definition inside node block I get this error. Method definition not expected here. Please define the method at an appropriate place or perhaps try using a block/Closure instead. I cannot do it outside like you mentioned as my pipeline runs on a specific node.

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you define your function. In the example, I provided the stage will always execute within your node.

Comment: Thanks @ycr you solved a big problem for me. Really appreciate.